# RegCreateKeyEx always returns 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED even when admin

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I'm really stuck...I have a Windows program that I'm trying to simply write a value to the Registry.

The problem is `RegCreateKeyEx()` returns 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`).

My logon username belongs to the local Administrators group.

The `lpdwDisposition` parameter in `RegCreateKeyEx()` gets set to 2 (`REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY`), but `RegCreateKeyEx()` still returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

It's a 32-bit program, so I have the SAM set to `KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_WRITE`

Here is minimal working example code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

void GetCurrentDateAndTimeWithMs(WCHAR *sValueData, DWORD dwSizeValueData)
{
    CONST INT iSize = 64;
    WCHAR sDate[iSize] = {0};
    WCHAR sTime[iSize] = {0};
    SYSTEMTIME lt = {0};

    GetLocalTime(&lt);
    GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NULL, &lt, NULL, sDate, iSize);
    GetTimeFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NULL, &lt, NULL, sTime, iSize);

    StringCchPrintf(sValueData, dwSizeValueData, L"%s %s.%u",sDate, sTime, lt.wMilliseconds);
}

DWORD SaveToRegistry(CONST WCHAR *sPath, CONST WCHAR *sValueName, CONST WCHAR *sValueData)
{
    LSTATUS dwRV = 0;
    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    DWORD rv = 0;
    DWORD dwType_Local = REG_SZ;

    dwRV = RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sPath, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, &rv);
    if (dwRV == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD dwLenData = (DWORD) wcslen(sValueData) +1;
        dwRV = RegSetValueExW(hKey, sValueName, 0, dwType_Local, (LPBYTE) sValueData, dwLenData * sizeof(WCHAR));
    }
    
    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return dwRV;
}

int main()
{
    WCHAR sDT[64] = {0};
    GetCurrentDateAndTimeWithMs(sDT, 64);
    SaveToRegistry(L"Software\\Company\\Product\\Settings", L"CurrentDateTime", sDT);
}
```

Comment: "*It's a 32-bit program, so I have the SAM set to `KEY_WOW64_32KEY | KEY_WRITE`*" - a 32bit program does not need to specify `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` to access the 32bit Registry view.  That is already the default behavior.  Same with a 64bit program and the 64bit Registry view.  You really only need to specify a `KEY_WOW64_...` flag when you want to access the *other* Registry view than your native view.

Comment: Good point. Still same behavior, `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: Have you tried `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead of `KEY_WRITE`? Don't ask for more permissions than you actually need. Do you absolutely need to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, why not `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`?

Comment: Yes, same behavior using `KEY_SET_VALUE` or `KEY_WRITE`.

Comment: Are you actually running with elevated rights? Running as an admin user, and running with elevated rights, are two different things. Do you have a UAC `requestedExecutionLevel` manifest in your app?

Comment: No, just an admin user. I thought an admin user have elevated rights by default? I guess not?! The manifest is set to `asInvoker`.

Comment: Unless the system actively prompts you for permission to elevate when the app is first run, then you are likely NOT running with elevated rights. And no, when UAC is enabled, an admin user does not have full rights without elevation.

Comment: I also tried turning UAC off and running it as a local admin. Still got `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to *completely* disable UAC on modern systems anymore. I might be wrong, though. But, did you at least reboot the machine after changing the UAC setting? You didn't answer my question though - do you have a `requestedExecutionLevel` manifest in your app?

Comment: I did restart it and still got `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Also, a Domain Admin can save to the Registry just fine. Not sure why? And yes, `<requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"          
          uiAccess="false"/>`

Comment: I don't think `asInvoker` will work in this situation, unless you manually tweak the Registry security policies to grant write access to HKLM to your user account. Otherwise, try `highestAvailable` or `requireAdministrator` instead (note, the latter will require refactoring this code into a separate process or COM object if you don't want your whole app to run elevated).

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Why, then, is a Domain Admin able to save but a local admin is not? But...if I run regedit.exe with the local admin, then I *can* save to the Registry!

Comment: `regedit.exe` sets `requestedExecutionLevel` to `highestAvailable`.

Comment: Set to highestAvailable and it works! Thank you!